# Notification ParentStack restart parent if app is in foreground

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

Before all, I need to notify that I have search on internet without success...

My problem is quite simple. My application can display at any moment a push notification (that should open `Event.class`). However, when the notification is displayed, the app could be in foreground or in background.

Following Google advice I have the following code

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Event.class);
resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
                        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
                        stackBuilder.addParentStack(Event.class);
                        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                        PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Here is my Manifest:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Event" android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".HomeContainer" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"  android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

</application>
```

**When the app is in background**

When I open the notification, the `Event.class` is created. When I click on the back_button, the `MainActivity.class` is created. That's normal and it's what I want.

**When the app is in foreground**

I'am on <del>`MainActivity.class`</del> **EDIT** `HomeContainer.class`. Then I open the notification and so the `Event.class` is created. When I click on the back_button, the `MainActivity.class` is recreated. I don't want that. Just want to `resume()` the <del>`MainActivity.class`</del> **EDIT** `Homecontainer.class` in this case.

---

How can I do ? I searched the different INTENT_FLAGS on Android documentation but nothing seems to be adapted.

Thanks in advance.

---

**As demanded by David Wasser,**
Result of : `adb shell dumpsys activity activities`

```
ACTIVITY MANAGER ACTIVITIES (dumpsys activity activities)
Display #0 (activities from top to bottom):
Stack #1:
mFullscreen=true
mBounds=null
Task id #3259
mFullscreen=true
mBounds=null
mMinWidth=-1
mMinHeight=-1
mLastNonFullscreenBounds=null
* TaskRecord{1d5ebe7 #3259 A=me.APPNAME.app U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
  userId=0 effectiveUid=u0a132 mCallingUid=u0a132 mUserSetupComplete=true mCallingPackage=me.APPNAME.app
  affinity=me.APPNAME.app
  intent={flg=0x18000000 cmp=me.APPNAME.app/.Event}
  realActivity=me.APPNAME.app/.Event
  autoRemoveRecents=false isPersistable=true numFullscreen=1 taskType=0 mTaskToReturnTo=0
  rootWasReset=false mNeverRelinquishIdentity=true mReuseTask=false mLockTaskAuth=LOCK_TASK_AUTH_PINNABLE
  Activities=[ActivityRecord{d8edb34 u0 me.APPNAME.app/.Event t3259}]
  askedCompatMode=false inRecents=true isAvailable=true
  lastThumbnail=null lastThumbnailFile=/data/system_ce/0/recent_images/3259_task_thumbnail.png
  stackId=1
  hasBeenVisible=true mResizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE isResizeable=true firstActiveTime=1519781736501 lastActiveTime=1519781736501 (inactive for 5s)
  * Hist #0: ActivityRecord{d8edb34 u0 me.APPNAME.app/.Event t3259}
      packageName=me.APPNAME.app processName=me.APPNAME.app
      launchedFromUid=10132 launchedFromPackage=me.APPNAME.app userId=0
      app=ProcessRecord{1e57f14 19075:me.APPNAME.app/u0a132}
      Intent { flg=0x18000000 cmp=me.APPNAME.app/.Event (has extras) }
      frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{1d5ebe7 #3259 A=me.APPNAME.app U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
      taskAffinity=me.APPNAME.app
      realActivity=me.APPNAME.app/.Event
      baseDir=/data/app/me.APPNAME.app-1/base.apk
      dataDir=/data/user/0/me.APPNAME.app
      splitDir=[/data/app/me.APPNAME.app-1/split_lib_directories_apk.apk]
      stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true mActivityType=0
      compat={384dpi} labelRes=0x7f100029 icon=0x7f0d0000 theme=0x7f110006
      config={1.0 208mcc15mnc [fr_FR] ldltr sw449dp w449dp h775dp 384dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.11}
      taskConfigOverride={1.0 ?mcc?mnc ?localeList ?layoutDir ?swdp ?wdp ?hdp ?density ?lsize ?long ?orien ?uimode ?night ?touch ?keyb/?/? ?nav/?}
      taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=ff1976d2
      launchFailed=false launchCount=1 lastLaunchTime=-5s734ms
      haveState=false icicle=null
      state=RESUMED stopped=false delayedResume=false finishing=false
      keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=true sleeping=false idle=true mStartingWindowState=STARTING_WINDOW_SHOWN
      fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=0
      frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
      mActivityType=APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_TYPE
      waitingVisible=false nowVisible=true lastVisibleTime=-5s9ms
      resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE
Task id #3258
mFullscreen=true
mBounds=null
mMinWidth=-1
mMinHeight=-1
mLastNonFullscreenBounds=null
* TaskRecord{1a00394 #3258 A=me.APPNAME.app U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
  userId=0 effectiveUid=u0a132 mCallingUid=u0a132 mUserSetupComplete=true mCallingPackage=me.APPNAME.app
  affinity=me.APPNAME.app
  intent={act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=me.APPNAME.app/.MainActivity}
  realActivity=me.APPNAME.app/.MainActivity
  autoRemoveRecents=false isPersistable=true numFullscreen=1 taskType=0 mTaskToReturnTo=1
  rootWasReset=true mNeverRelinquishIdentity=true mReuseTask=false mLockTaskAuth=LOCK_TASK_AUTH_PINNABLE
  Activities=[ActivityRecord{e5f96d1 u0 me.APPNAME.app/.HomeContainer t3258}]
  askedCompatMode=false inRecents=false isAvailable=true
  lastThumbnail=null lastThumbnailFile=/data/system_ce/0/recent_images/3258_task_thumbnail.png
  stackId=1
  hasBeenVisible=true mResizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE isResizeable=true firstActiveTime=1519781736451 lastActiveTime=1519781736451 (inactive for 5s)
  * Hist #0: ActivityRecord{e5f96d1 u0 me.APPNAME.app/.HomeContainer t3258}
      packageName=me.APPNAME.app processName=me.APPNAME.app
      launchedFromUid=10132 launchedFromPackage=me.APPNAME.app userId=0
      app=ProcessRecord{1e57f14 19075:me.APPNAME.app/u0a132}
      Intent { flg=0x10000 cmp=me.APPNAME.app/.HomeContainer }
      frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{1a00394 #3258 A=me.APPNAME.app U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
      taskAffinity=me.APPNAME.app
      realActivity=me.APPNAME.app/.HomeContainer
      baseDir=/data/app/me.APPNAME.app-1/base.apk
      dataDir=/data/user/0/me.APPNAME.app
      splitDir=[/data/app/me.APPNAME.app-1/split_lib_directories_apk.apk]
      stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true mActivityType=0
      compat={384dpi} labelRes=0x7f100029 icon=0x7f0d0000 theme=0x7f110006
      config={1.0 208mcc15mnc [fr_FR] ldltr sw449dp w449dp h775dp 384dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.11}
      taskConfigOverride={1.0 ?mcc?mnc ?localeList ?layoutDir ?swdp ?wdp ?hdp ?density ?lsize ?long ?orien ?uimode ?night ?touch ?keyb/?/? ?nav/?}
      taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=ff1976d2
      launchFailed=false launchCount=0 lastLaunchTime=-35s758ms
      haveState=true icicle=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=14188]
      state=STOPPED stopped=true delayedResume=false finishing=false
      keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=false sleeping=false idle=true mStartingWindowState=STARTING_WINDOW_NOT_SHOWN
      fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=0
      frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
      mActivityType=APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_TYPE
      waitingVisible=false nowVisible=false lastVisibleTime=-33s336ms
      resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE
Task id #3185
mFullscreen=true
mBounds=null
mMinWidth=-1
mMinHeight=-1
mLastNonFullscreenBounds=null
* TaskRecord{ec402a4 #3185 I=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
  userId=0 effectiveUid=u0a43 mCallingUid=u0a43 mUserSetupComplete=true mCallingPackage=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
  intent={flg=0x10808000 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity}
  realActivity=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity
  autoRemoveRecents=false isPersistable=false numFullscreen=1 taskType=0 mTaskToReturnTo=1
  rootWasReset=false mNeverRelinquishIdentity=true mReuseTask=false mLockTaskAuth=LOCK_TASK_AUTH_PINNABLE
  Activities=[ActivityRecord{6387e63 u0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity t3185}]
  askedCompatMode=false inRecents=true isAvailable=true
  lastThumbnail=null lastThumbnailFile=/data/system_ce/0/recent_images/3185_task_thumbnail.png
  stackId=1
  hasBeenVisible=true mResizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_UNRESIZEABLE isResizeable=false firstActiveTime=1519761319987 lastActiveTime=1519761319987 (inactive for 20422s)
  * Hist #0: ActivityRecord{6387e63 u0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity t3185}
      packageName=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox processName=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search
      launchedFromUid=10043 launchedFromPackage=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox userId=0
      app=ProcessRecord{54c0ce7 16531:com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search/u0a43}
      Intent { flg=0x10808000 cmp=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity (has extras) }
      frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{ec402a4 #3185 I=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
      taskAffinity=null
      realActivity=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity
      baseDir=/data/app/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox-1/base.apk
      dataDir=/data/user/0/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
      stateNotNeeded=false componentSpecified=true mActivityType=0
      compat={384dpi} labelRes=0x7f140c2b icon=0x7f02047c theme=0x7f1501ec
      config={1.0 208mcc15mnc [fr_FR] ldltr sw449dp w449dp h775dp 384dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.11}
      taskConfigOverride={1.0 ?mcc?mnc ?localeList ?layoutDir ?swdp ?wdp ?hdp ?density ?lsize ?long ?orien ?uimode ?night ?touch ?keyb/?/? ?nav/?}
      taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=ff4285f4
      launchFailed=false launchCount=0 lastLaunchTime=-5h31m17s606ms
      haveState=true icicle=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=5644]
      state=STOPPED stopped=true delayedResume=false finishing=false
      keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=false sleeping=false idle=true mStartingWindowState=STARTING_WINDOW_NOT_SHOWN
      fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=2
      frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
      mActivityType=APPLICATION_ACTIVITY_TYPE
      waitingVisible=false nowVisible=false lastVisibleTime=-5h9m27s823ms
      resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_UNRESIZEABLE

Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{1d5ebe7 #3259 A=me.APPNAME.app U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
    Run #2: ActivityRecord{d8edb34 u0 me.APPNAME.app/.Event t3259}
  TaskRecord{1a00394 #3258 A=me.APPNAME.app U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
    Run #1: ActivityRecord{e5f96d1 u0 me.APPNAME.app/.HomeContainer t3258}
  TaskRecord{ec402a4 #3185 I=com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity U=0 StackId=1 sz=1}
    Run #0: ActivityRecord{6387e63 u0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.opa.OpaActivity t3185}

  mResumedActivity: ActivityRecord{d8edb34 u0 me.APPNAME.app/.Event t3259}
  mLastPausedActivity: ActivityRecord{e5f96d1 u0 me.APPNAME.app/.HomeContainer t3258}

Stack #0:
mFullscreen=true
mBounds=null
Task id #2488
mFullscreen=true
mBounds=null
mMinWidth=-1
mMinHeight=-1
mLastNonFullscreenBounds=null
* TaskRecord{f9fd3c2 #2488 I=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
  userId=0 effectiveUid=u0a83 mCallingUid=u0a29 mUserSetupComplete=true mCallingPackage=com.android.systemui
  intent={act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000100 cmp=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity}
  realActivity=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity
  autoRemoveRecents=false isPersistable=true numFullscreen=1 taskType=1 mTaskToReturnTo=1
  rootWasReset=false mNeverRelinquishIdentity=true mReuseTask=false mLockTaskAuth=LOCK_TASK_AUTH_PINNABLE
  Activities=[ActivityRecord{871cda8 u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t2488}]
  askedCompatMode=false inRecents=true isAvailable=true
  lastThumbnail=null lastThumbnailFile=/data/system_ce/0/recent_images/2488_task_thumbnail.png
  stackId=0
  hasBeenVisible=true mResizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE isResizeable=false firstActiveTime=1519781704569 lastActiveTime=1519781704569 (inactive for 37s)
  * Hist #0: ActivityRecord{871cda8 u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t2488}
      packageName=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher processName=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher
      launchedFromUid=0 launchedFromPackage=null userId=0
      app=ProcessRecord{275537b 13195:com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/u0a83}
      Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000100 cmp=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity }
      frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{f9fd3c2 #2488 I=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
      taskAffinity=null
      realActivity=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity
      baseDir=/data/app/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher-1/base.apk
      dataDir=/data/user/0/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher
      stateNotNeeded=true componentSpecified=false mActivityType=1
      compat={384dpi} labelRes=0x7f0c008c icon=0x7f02002b theme=0x7f120002
      config={1.0 208mcc15mnc [fr_FR] ldltr sw449dp w449dp h775dp 384dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.11}
      taskConfigOverride={1.0 ?mcc?mnc ?localeList ?layoutDir ?swdp ?wdp ?hdp ?density ?lsize ?long ?orien ?uimode ?night ?touch ?keyb/?/? ?nav/?}
      taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=fff5f5f5
      launchFailed=false launchCount=0 lastLaunchTime=-3d3h30m22s60ms
      haveState=true icicle=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=5208]
      state=STOPPED stopped=true delayedResume=false finishing=false
      keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=false sleeping=false idle=true mStartingWindowState=STARTING_WINDOW_NOT_SHOWN
      fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=2
      frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
      mActivityType=HOME_ACTIVITY_TYPE
      waitingVisible=false nowVisible=false lastVisibleTime=-38s713ms
      connections=[]
      resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE

Task id #2490
mFullscreen=true
mBounds=null
mMinWidth=-1
mMinHeight=-1
mLastNonFullscreenBounds=null
* TaskRecord{39e75d3 #2490 A=com.android.systemui U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
  userId=0 effectiveUid=u0a29 mCallingUid=u0a29 mUserSetupComplete=true mCallingPackage=com.android.systemui
  affinity=com.android.systemui
  intent={flg=0x10804000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity bnds=[38,1727][1042,3206]}
  realActivity=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity
  autoRemoveRecents=false isPersistable=false numFullscreen=1 taskType=2 mTaskToReturnTo=1
  rootWasReset=false mNeverRelinquishIdentity=true mReuseTask=false mLockTaskAuth=LOCK_TASK_AUTH_PINNABLE
  Activities=[ActivityRecord{52e27f8 u0 com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity t2490}]
  askedCompatMode=false inRecents=true isAvailable=true
  lastThumbnail=null lastThumbnailFile=/data/system_ce/0/recent_images/2490_task_thumbnail.png
  stackId=0
  hasBeenVisible=true mResizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE isResizeable=true firstActiveTime=1519781703116 lastActiveTime=1519781703116 (inactive for 39s)
  * Hist #0: ActivityRecord{52e27f8 u0 com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity t2490}
      packageName=com.android.systemui processName=com.android.systemui
      launchedFromUid=10029 launchedFromPackage=com.android.systemui userId=0
      app=ProcessRecord{cd948d2 12010:com.android.systemui/u0a29}
      Intent { flg=0x10804000 cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity bnds=[38,1727][1042,3206] }
      frontOfTask=true task=TaskRecord{39e75d3 #2490 A=com.android.systemui U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
      taskAffinity=com.android.systemui
      realActivity=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity
      baseDir=/system/priv-app/SystemUI/SystemUI.apk
      dataDir=/data/user_de/0/com.android.systemui
      stateNotNeeded=true componentSpecified=true mActivityType=2
      compat={384dpi} labelRes=0x7f0d02b9 icon=0x7f020175 theme=0x7f1301ea
      config={1.0 208mcc15mnc [fr_FR] ldltr sw449dp w449dp h775dp 384dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h s.7}
      taskConfigOverride={1.0 ?mcc?mnc ?localeList ?layoutDir ?swdp ?wdp ?hdp ?density ?lsize ?long ?orien ?uimode ?night ?touch ?keyb/?/? ?nav/?}
      taskDescription: iconFilename=null label="null" color=ff212121
      launchFailed=false launchCount=0 lastLaunchTime=-3d3h11m55s774ms
      haveState=true icicle=Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=500]
      state=STOPPED stopped=true delayedResume=false finishing=false
      keysPaused=false inHistory=true visible=false sleeping=false idle=true mStartingWindowState=STARTING_WINDOW_NOT_SHOWN
      fullscreen=true noDisplay=false immersive=false launchMode=3
      frozenBeforeDestroy=false forceNewConfig=false
      mActivityType=RECENTS_ACTIVITY_TYPE
      waitingVisible=false nowVisible=false lastVisibleTime=-41s902ms
      resizeMode=RESIZE_MODE_RESIZEABLE

Running activities (most recent first):
  TaskRecord{f9fd3c2 #2488 I=com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
    Run #1: ActivityRecord{871cda8 u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t2488}
  TaskRecord{39e75d3 #2490 A=com.android.systemui U=0 StackId=0 sz=1}
    Run #0: ActivityRecord{52e27f8 u0 com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity t2490}

mLastPausedActivity: ActivityRecord{871cda8 u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t2488}

mFocusedActivity: ActivityRecord{d8edb34 u0 me.APPNAME.app/.Event t3259}
mFocusedStack=ActivityStack{690a510 stackId=1, 10 tasks} 
mLastFocusedStack=ActivityStack{690a510 stackId=1, 10 tasks}
mSleepTimeout=false
mCurTaskIdForUser={0=3259}
mUserStackInFront={}
mActivityContainers={0=ActivtyContainer{0}A, 1=ActivtyContainer{1}A}
mLockTaskModeState=NONE mLockTaskPackages (userId:packages)=
0:[]
mLockTaskModeTasks[]
```

**The updated code I tried (following the advice of David Wasser) :**

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Event.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
/** remove uninteresting lines */
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channel_id);
notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent); 
/** other parameters as title, icons etc */
notificationManager.notify(_id, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK`. This is very special and will get you into trouble and is not needed and isn't what you want.

Do not use `TaskStackBuilder`. This constructs an `Intent` that will clear out any existing task when the `Notification` is opened. This is why, when the app is running, you get the same behaviour as when the app is not running.

Just do this:

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Event.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

This will launch `Event` into an existing task (if the app is running), or create a new task and launch `Event` into that task. If you want `MainActivity` to be started if the user presses the BACK key (and the app was not already running), do this:

In `Event` override `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (isTaskRoot()) {
        // This Activity is the root Activity, so start `MainActivity`
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        // Just use the default implementation
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: I thank to this solution but was thinking there was an other better way. Apparently not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by "better way"?

Comment: Sorry I have mistaken with `List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > task = manager.getRunningTasks(1);` that is recommanded for debug only. But there, you only use `isTaskRoot()`. Your answer is consequently perfect ! Thanks

Comment: Actually I just tried and `isTaskRoot` is always true even if the app was in foreground... Do you know how to solve that ?

Comment: Sorry, that makes no sense at all. Please run `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` and find your task and post the output of your task.

Comment: I updated my question with the asked output. The scenario was the following : I launched the App, so `MainActivity` started. I opened `HomeContainer`. I received the notification and I clicked on it. So `Event` started. There I executed the adb command.

Comment: In your original post you said nothing about `HomeContainer`. Please post the manifest entry for that. You are ending up with 2 tasks here which is why `isTaskRoot()` returns true. We need to figure out why `Event` is not launched into the exising task (which it should be). Also please update the post to show the code you are now using to create the `Notification`

Comment: I didn't mentioned `HomeContainer` to simplify the problem but indeed it's more confusing than anything else (adding that's make no sense to use my initial Stackbuilder solution).  I updated the post as requested. I don't understand why it's normal that `isTaskRoot()` return true. Knowing that there are 2 tasks, it should return false no ? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: No. Android is returning `true` from `isTaskRoot()` because it started a new task with `Event`. But it shouldn't do that. It should launch `Event` into the existing task. I do not understand. There's something else going on here that I cannot explain based on the stuff you've posted. How is `HomeContainer` launched? How is `MainActivity` launched?

Comment: `isTaskRoot()` returns `true` if the `Activity` that calls it is the **root** `Activity (ie: the first one) in the task.

Comment: `MainActivity` is launched from the launcher (clicking on the app's icon) and `HomeContainer` is launched by the following line `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeContainer.class)); finish();`. Maybe we should add some `FLAGS` to the `Event` intent : `Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, Event.class);` no ?

Comment: I see no reason why Android would start a new task when launching `Event` from the `Notification`. Are you sure that you aren't using a special `launchMode` or other `Intent` flags anywhere? The behaviour you are showing makes no sense. Please try the following: kill the app (settings->Apps->YourApp->Force close). Then launch the app from the home screen, then start `HomeContainer`. Then click on the `Notification` and check with `adb shell dumpsys activity activities` that you still have 2 tasks (`TaskRecord` with `A=me.APPNAME.app`.

Comment: I don't know why but it's working now ! I edited anything... Anyway, thanks for my time and your precious help.

Comment: Good to hear that! Glad you were able to solve the problem.

Comment: The best approach i found to do this. Thank you!